# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in React while fetching external API

Tags: reactjs, api

I am trying to fetch some photos using external API - Unsplash in React  and getting the error = (see in title). API seems to work totally fine, since when I console log its there, but somehow I can not to print it out. Can you see if I am making mistake somewhere ?? I am really getting lost, already spent hours by trying to figure out.

This is my code :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";


const PhotoList = () => {
  const [photography, setPhotography] = useState("");
  const [clientId, setClientId] = useState(
    "MyAPIKey"
  );
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = ev => {
    setPhotography(ev.target.value);
  };
  const handleSubmit = ev => {
    console.log(photography);

    const url =
      "https://api.unsplash.com/photos?page=1&query" +
      photography +
      "&client_id=" +
      clientId;

    axios.get(url).then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      setResult(response.data.results);
    });
  };
```

And returning in HTML :

```
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Here is the list of the photos</h1>
      <input
        onChange={handleChange}
        type="text"
        name="photography"
        placeholder="Get more inspiration here"
      ></input>
      <button onClick={handleSubmit} type="submit">
        Search
      </button>

      {result.map(photography => (
        <img src={photography.urls.small} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default PhotoList;
```

Comment: Can you post the API response body?

Comment: @Paul Do you mean the whole API JSON file ? its bit too long :D

Comment: If you have a GitHub account, you can create a public Gist, then just post the link here.  If not, can you paste just a relevant snippet?

Comment: @Paul I put on GitHub - this is the response I am getting when searching for "nature" photos:  https://github.com/GirlCodesCopenhagen/ReactAPI/blob/master/Response.json

Comment: Is `results` a key in the response body?  Currently I'm thinking you're callback should be `setResult(response.data);`

Comment: @Paul you are hero of my day  :) daaamn and this took me so long! that was the issue, now its working ..Thank you ❤️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the API response body, the API callback should be:

```
setResult(response.data);
```

The `results` key does not exist in the API response body.